# Execute PHP code in a string

Tags: php, eval

I have my page contents saved in a database and would like to execute any php code in the string. So if my string was:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1><?php echo $motto?><br/>
```

I only want to execute `echo $motto`. Using eval() will try to execute `<h1>Welcome</h1>`.

Any way to do this?

Comment: yes keep presentation and logic seperate.  Having to do this would indicate that you might want to rethink your design choices.

Comment: For the way you're structuring your site, I can tell you right now this will cause problems down the line. Here's my suggestion: use Smarty, or similar, to separate templates and code.

Comment: This seems like you have made a really **really** bad design decision.

Comment: The only thing I am trying to load is the main body. The headers, footers and sidebars are all saved in files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Needless to say you should find another solution ASAP. In the meantime you can eval the code like this:

```
$str = '<h1>Welcome</h1><?php echo $motto?><br/>'; // Your DB content

eval("?> $str <?php ");
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/ao2PPHN7

I can't stress that enough: eval is dangerous, and application code shouldn't be in the database. Try a template parser like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Dwoo](http://wiki.dwoo.org), or my favorite: [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: ...or simply `eval("?> $str");` You just have to jump out of the PHP block.

Answer (score 2):

You **really** shouldn't do this, but if you absolutely have to, you can do it by using this class:

```
class PhpStringParser
{
    protected $variables;

    public function __construct($variables = array())
    {
        $this->variables = $variables;
    }

    protected function eval_block($matches)
    {
        if( is_array($this->variables) && count($this->variables) )
        {
            foreach($this->variables as $var_name => $var_value)
            {
                $$var_name = $var_value;
            }
        }

        $eval_end = '';

        if( $matches[1] == '<?=' || $matches[1] == '<?php=' )
        {
            if( $matches[2][count($matches[2]-1)] !== ';' )
            {
                $eval_end = ';';
            }
        }

        $return_block = '';

        eval('$return_block = ' . $matches[2] . $eval_end);

        return $return_block;
    }

    public function parse($string)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback('/(\<\?=|\<\?php=|\<\?php)(.*?)\?\>/', array(&$this, 'eval_block'), $string);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$p = new PhpStringParser();
echo $p->parse($string);
```

<sup>*Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#108091*</sup>

Comment: The reason the main body is saved in a database is so the client can edit it in a custom windows program I have made. I am trying to set it up differently but in the mean time the site needs to go online like this.

Comment: What benefit does the above have compared to `ob_start();eval("?>$str");$result=ob_get_clean();`?

Answer (score 2):

To echo string with a variable inside use:

```
echo "<h1>Welcome</h1>$motto<br/>"
```

Or even:

```
echo sprintf('<h1>Welcome</h1>%s<br/>', $motto)
```

Here is a demo http://codepad.org/f6aALD6w