# PHP echo inside echo

Tags: php, html, sql, echo

I'm trying to call an HTML/PHP content that it's inside my database using:

```
<?php echo $row_content['conteudo']; ?>
```

When the row is called the HTML appears correctly but the PHP doesn't.
I belieave it's cause of the echo inside the main echo.

```
<?php echo "
<h3>Hello</h3>
<?php do { ?>
  <div class=\"indios\">
    <a href=\"indio.php?id=<?php echo $row_indiosct['id']; ?>\">
      <img src=\"galeria/indios/<?php echo $row_indiosct['foto']; ?>\" alt=\"<?php echo $row_indiosct['nome']; ?>\" />
      <br /><?php echo $row_indiosct['nome']; ?></a></div>
  <?php } while ($row_indiosct = mysql_fetch_assoc($indiosct)); ?> "
 ?>
```

The line one of this code is the same echo as the first code field, it's not repeating, it's there just for help and to understand where is the problem.

I already fixed some quotation marks but it gives an error in the line of the 1st echo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is some of the ugliest code I have ever seen...

```
<?php 
echo '
<h3>Hello</h3>';

while ($row_indiosct = mysql_fetch_assoc($indiosct))
{
  echo '
    <div class="indios">
      <a href="indio.php?id='.$row_indiosct['id'].'">
        <img src="galeria/indios/'. $row_indiosct['foto'].'" alt="'.$row_indiosct['nome'].'" />
      <br />'.$row_indiosct['nome'].'</a>
    </div>';
} 
?>
```

You could also use the [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Multi-line echoes, especially when you've got embedded quotes, quickly become a pain. Use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead.

```
<?php 

echo <<<EOL
<h3>Hello</h3>
...
<div class"indios">
...
EOL;
```

and yes, the PHP inside your echo will **NOT** execute. PHP is not a "recursively executable" language. If you're outputting a string, any php code embedded in that string is not executed - it'll be treated as part of the output, e.g.

```
echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>"
```

is **NOT** going to output just `foo`. You'll actually get as output

```
<?php echo 'foo' ?>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood how PHP works. PHP is processed by the server. When it encounters your script, it sees the following:

```
<?php echo "some long piece of text that you have told PHP not to look at" ?>
```

What is the reasoning behind trying to nest PHP calls inside strings?

Answer (score 0):

evaluate code php in string using the function eval(): this post [Execute PHP code in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866301/execute-php-code-in-a-string)

```php
<?php
$motto = 'Hello';
$str = '<h1>Welcome</h1><?php echo $motto?><br/>';
eval("?> $str <?php ");
```

http://codepad.org/ao2PPHN7

also if your need the code buffer output in a string also you can using the ob_start() method:

```php
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<h3>Hello</h3>;

<?php 
  while ($row_indiosct = mysql_fetch_assoc($indiosct)){ ?>

<div class="indios">
  <a href="indio.php?id='<?php echo $row_indiosct['id']'">
    <img src="galeria/indios/'<?php echo $row_indiosct['foto'].'" alt="'.$row_indiosct['nome'].'" />
  <br />'.$row_indiosct['nome'].'</a>
</div>';

<?php } ?>
```