# How to pass a value and echo it within a form

Tags: php

hello i have a page where users can register, and so after registeration i want to pass the username and password from my registeration form to another form on a next page, mean while this form on the next page should hold username and password values that are passed from the first page.

the form is echoed correctly but the values dont come correctly.

this is what i ahve tried

```
echo '<form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" METHOD="POST" name="one" id="one">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username" value="<?php echo $_POST["Username"]; ?>" >
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" value="<?php echo $_POST["Password"]; ?>">
              <br>
              <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In" />

              </form>';
```

but the values dont come out, is there a right way to echoe this thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP echo inside echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477025/php-echo-inside-echo)

Comment: so can u advise on wat to be done please

Comment: You can use `Session Variables` to store the values of the first form.

Comment: @toluodumbo To correct your code look at the answer on the duplicate + look into `$_SESSION` for storing your values

Comment: and then do wat, can u explain with an example using a form,

Comment: You can learn the basics about session variables on the link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp . It would be better if you try this on your own instead of me giving you the solution. It will be good for your learning purpose.

Comment: ok thanks appreciate

Comment: Firstly, you can't have PHP tags inside an echo (*why? You're already in PHP*), then echo inside that echo (*why? You're already echoing*). Second; show us the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<form ACTION="'.$loginFormAction.'" METHOD="POST" name="one" id="one">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username" value="'.$_POST["Username"].'" >
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" value=".'$_POST["Password"].'">
              <br>
              <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In" />

              </form>';
```

Try This And Reply

Comment: it works but i am now having this error Notice: Undefined variable: loginFormAction in C:\xampp\htdocs\kbluser\connect.php on line 29, which has to do with form action

Comment: then give some value to the variable $loginFormAction
eg. $loginFormAction="targetfile.php"

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this with echo, because the echo is just some HTML on the other page. You can also save them.

What you want is a form most likely:

Page 1

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Page2

```
<?php
echo "Your sent username: ", $_POST['username'];
?>
```