# Using PHP inside quotes

Tags: php

I am trying to repopulate the post value of a text box in php. My html is built dynamically using a string and I am struggling with single and double quotes in the html string while using the php code. Below is my code

```
function setTestboxValue(){

        $text = "<form action = '' method = 'post'>
                   <input type='text'  name='title' 
                    value='<?php echo isset($_POST['textValue']) ? $_POST['textValue'] : '' ?>' 
                       placeholder = 'book name' />                       
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search' />
                    </form>";
        return $text;
}
```

I am facing issue with "Possible Syntax error. unexpected variable: $_POST". Would really appreciate if some one can help me with this issue.

**Disclaimer:**
I started working on php since a week, so I am an absolute newbie to php.

Comment: it's because you're already in PHP and using php tags and echo. Take this as an answer to this question.

Comment: `$text = @"<html> ... value='$array[key]' ... </html>"`

Comment: `value='". isset($_POST['textValue']) ? $_POST['textValue'] : '' ."'`

Comment: ^ you guys don't feel confident enough? *lol* Edit: ah I see... question was closed, wasn't fast enough.

Comment: Not today Fred, its all yours

Comment: I was going for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477025/php-echo-inside-echo

Comment: @Xorifelse hehehe, I was busy going for a dupe for it, but Machavity found it.

Comment: @Xorifelse i tried your suggestion, but now I get undefinex index:textValue error. I guess the isset check isnt working as expected..?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I expected as much, by all yours I meant "flag it as a dupe" :), as for NoobGeek, have you checked the line number where it happened? Most likely not my line of code...

Comment: @Xorifelse it is indeed on that line of code you suggested.