# How can I return a php code from a php function?

Tags: php, function, web

```
<?php 
    function A() {
        return "<?php echo \"some text\"; ?>";
    }
    echo A();
?>
```

I expected to see "some text" on the page, but i did not.
So how do I make this code work? Thanks in advance.

UPD:
I'm sorry for the not clear description.
I'm going to insert a random number into the value of the input.

```
<?php 
 function print_form() {
    return "<form method=\"POST\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"code1\" value=\" <?php echo rand(0, 999999); ?> \" />
    </form>"; 
 }
    echo print_form(); ?>
```

Comment: Well... you are including `<?php` inside another `<?php`

Comment: you can use [**eval**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866301/execute-php-code-in-a-string).... but __at your own risk!__

Comment: I think real question is "how do you insert a block of PHP code as the result of a function?  I think you should consider using includes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the return of the function:

```
return "<form method=\"POST\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"code1\" value=\"" . rand(0, 999999) . "\" />
</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

mate you have to return the text not a PHP code:

```
<?php 
    function A() {
        return "some text";
    }
    echo A();
?>
```

Comment: this is not the answer according to the question. he wants to run the code inside the function and return the output. not just output the string.

Comment: @itachi Not really: `I expected to see "some text" on the page`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
 function print_form() {
    return '<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="code1" value="'.rand(0, 999999).'" />
    </form>'; 
 }
    echo print_form(); ?>
```

you are returning, so just concatenent the value.