# Having PHP inside PHP Values

Tags: php, html

I'm just wondering on how I'd be able to use PHP coding in PHP variables?
So for example.
I want something like

```
$Start = " IF($lala == "0"){ echo '";
$End = " '; }";
```

and to be able to use it as

```
echo ''.$start.' hello '.End.'';
```

It may sound weird, but I'd like it to be done in a similar way to this.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I guess this will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: `$start != $Start`,  and `End != $End`

Comment: wow, totally weird! just out of curiosity what is the use case? I'm sure we can find a much better alternative.

Comment: I want to do this, because, well its strange, but i'm going to be using the exact same if statement about 20 times, and I'm using str_replace to use {Start} tags inside the html. Which I don't wan to be using php inside. So pretty much I want to be able to use {Start} and for it to turn out the result for $Start which will give me the if statement.

Comment: This is such a humugously bad idea!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Any suggestions on a better way?

Comment: Why not use a function? What you described is the exact use case for a function.

Comment: Perhaps a `switch` - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP code in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866301/execute-php-code-in-a-string)

Comment: Let's put it this way: lots of PHP apps have been written without resorting to this weirdness. That should be an indication that it's either not a good idea and/or that it's at least not very feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I can't even begin to tell you how dangerous executing code from a string is. So don't even think about it...

Instead use a function or a Closure (once you feel somewhat safe with PHP)

```
<?php
function myFunction($str) {
  $lala = lalaFunction();
  if ($lala) { return $str; }
}
```

And then just call:

```
echo myFunction('something');
```

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go! Do NOT use eval ().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using `eval()`:

```
<?php
    $lala = 0;
    $Start = "if($lala == '0'){ echo ";
    $End = ";}";
    eval($Start.'hello'.$End);
?>
```

output:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

in that case for if condition you can simply write the code like this:

```
<?php
$check=0;
$x='true';
$y='false';
$value=$check==0?$y:$x;
?>
```

in this `$check==0` is used for if AND `?` is used for the event to run if condition passed is true and `:` is used for else part.